# What is the life story of Curtis Chen in Continuum?

Tags: continuum

In the excellent Canadian science fiction show *Continuum*, Curtis Chen is one of the Liber8 terrorists who traveled to the past.  Here are some facts that we know about him:

- In Season 2 we see a flashback that shows that before he went to the past, he had black dots in his fingers, indicating that he was actually a member of the Freelancers the whole time.
- After he goes to the past, he is killed by Kiera in season 1.
- He is revived by the Traveler, the founder of the Freelancers, by taking his consciousness from another timeline and merging it with his dead body.
- In the Green timeline (the new timeline created by Alec's time-traveling), he shoots Green Kiera but fails to kill her, and then Brad Tomkin, the future soldier from the Green timeline future, kills Green Kiera.
- In season 3, when Kiera asks Curtis why he didn't stop Liber8 from going to the past and thus prevent the timeline from changing in the first place, he explains that suicide goes against his beliefs.  (If Liber8 didn't go to the past they would have been executed in 2077.)
- In season 3, he tells someone that the Freelancers aren't the disciples of the Traveler, they're his jailers, and later he kills the Freelancers and frees the Traveler.
- In season 4 he spends his time carrying out the orders of the Traveler.
- Close to the end of season 4, someone (maybe Garza) tells him "You've been playing both sides from the beginning, so why should I trust you?"  And he replies "I've changed."

So my question is, what is the life story of Curtis Chen?  Was he a time-traveler before he ever left 2077?  Or did the Freelancers cult still exist in 2077, and was he just a person in 2077 who decided to sign up for the Freelancers?

In any case, why did Curtis shoot Green Kiera?  Was he working with Brad Tomkin, and if so why?  His attempt to kill Green Kiera wasn't sanctioned by the Freelancers, and in fact when they found out they locked him up (although he escaped).  So why did he do it?  Was he secretly following the orders of Traveler?

And when and how did he switch from the side of the Freelancers to the side of the Traveler?  The switch obviously must have happened before he freed the Traveler.  In any case I'm not even sure what the differences are between the Traveler and the Freelancers, but that may be better left for another question.